# clearTimeout within it's own function while running

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, settimeout

I'm trying to call a function which clears the timeOut (to stop an animation loop) while the function is running. This is what I'm trying at the moment:

```
function gameStop(){
  clearTimeout(gameLoop);
}

function gameLoop() {
  $('h1').show("slow")
           .animate({"marginLeft":"300px"},4000)
            .animate({"marginLeft":"0px"},4000);
 $('h1').click(function(){
   gameStop();
 });
 gameLoop();
}

 setTimeout(gameLoop, 4000);

 gameLoop();
```

Comment: `clearTimeout` does accept the *timeout ID* which is returned by `setTimeout`, not the scheduled function.

Comment: For this to become a game loop, you had to place the `setTimeout` in the `gameLoop` function. Yours will just call it twice.

Answer (score 0):

Wow to be honest, this looks pretty messed up.
First, you don't want to add click events in every gameloop, so please put this somewhere outside of your game loop.
Second: clearing the timeout doesn't work like this.
And nasting functions with the same name is pretty bad in general...

Try something like this (don't know if the code works or if your loop makes any sense, but this is actually what you want I think).

```
var timeOut = null;  

$('h1').click(function(){
clearTimeout(timeOut);
});

function gameLoop(){
$('h1').show("slow")
    .animate({"marginLeft":"300px"},4000)
    .animate({"marginLeft":"0px"},4000);
};
timeOut = setTimeout(gameLoop, 4000);
```

Comment: There are a few errors (because I typed out the example quickly) so I'll fix that up now, but the whole point of the question is that the clearTimeout function has to be called within the loop.

Comment: no you actually don't call it within the loop, you call it whenever the user clicks on h1, right? because you add an event handle to h1 on click...
This means, you can remove that code out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need the `setTimeout`, use the force, Luke!
 Use the `.animate()` callback to loop your function:

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/iBOToQo/1/edit)

```
jQuery(function($) { // DOM ready

    function gameLoop() {
      $('h1').show("slow")
           .animate({marginLeft: 300}, 4000)
           .animate({marginLeft: 0  }, 4000, gameLoop); // LOOP HERE
    }
    gameLoop(); // START

    $('h1').click(function(){
       $(this).stop();
    });

});
```

or even simpler: **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/iBOToQo/3/edit)**

```
var mrg = [300,0];

(function gameLoop() {
  $('h1').animate({marginLeft: mrg.reverse()[1]}, 4000, gameLoop);
})();

$('h1').click(function(){
   $(this).stop();
});
```

caching your selector for a slightly better performance
and animating depending on the current margin position: **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/iBOToQo/4/edit)**

```
var $h1 = $('h1'); // Cache your selectors

(function gameLoop() {
  var m = parseInt( $h1.css('marginLeft'), 10);
  $h1.animate({marginLeft: m>0?0:300 }, 4000, gameLoop);
})();

$h1.click(function(){
   $(this).stop();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would store the timout in a variable and a flag to indicate if the user has stopped the game:

something like this (not tested)

```
var timeOut = null; 

var stopped = false; 

$('h1').click(function(){
stopped = true;
});

function gameLoop()
{
      clearTimeout(timeOut);

     $('h1').show("slow")
    .animate({"marginLeft":"300px"},4000)
    .animate({"marginLeft":"0px"},4000);

     if (!stopped)
     {
          timeOut = setTimeout(gameLoop, 100);
     }
};

timeOut = setTimeout(gameLoop, 4000);
```